# how to resolve a response multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

so i have a fucntion which would return a Value
for example :

```
let  value= function () =>{
//basically getting values from an api 

let get = axios.get("example.com").then(res=>{
Value = res
})
//     Value is the value that had been retrieved from a  Get request from an API 
return Value ; 

}
module.export = {value}
```

^^ That is the first file  in the secound file i want to get the values of use the them , the problem here that in the first time i use the function :

```
const first_file = require("./first_file") 

first_file.then(res=>{
console.log(res)
})
```

the first time i use the fucntion very thing would be fine but sometimes in case of an error i would call the function again using try catch method , this would return the same response i got first time

Sorry For the bad explanation

Comment: I think you just export `get` and then do something like like `first_file.then(res => ..., err => ...);`.

Comment: HI, so am recalling the function when an error occurred from another function not the same one , Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to understand what you want. But if a call crash probably you shouldn't do it again.
But if you want to do something whatever it is when your call crash you can use `.catch` after `.then`.

Edit your function `value` to return the axios call.

```
let value = function () => {
     return axios.get("example.com")
}

module.export = {value}
```

Then you can access it like this :

```
const first_file = require("./first_file") 

first_file.value.then(res=>{
    console.log(res)
}).catch(error => {
// For exemple you can log the error, or do whatever you want here
   console.log(error) 
})
```

Comment: hi , thank you for the answer when an error occur (not from the function ) i want to recall the function , the problem here when i recall the function i would get the same answer from the first call , sorry for the unclarity

Comment: It is normal that you get the same answer. If you calling for exemple `http://i-do-not-exist.zut` and then you try to re-call the same address in the `.catch` for exemple it will still not exit and will still have the same status like 404.

My point is if you have an error from your backend or an url and try to recall the same url in the catch you will still have the same error

Comment: when i recall the function the error would not be from GET the url it would be another thing , but yeah THank you